# Print result of timestamp function one line before string

Tags: json, object, awk, timestamp, jq

At the bottom is some example json data which I'd like to add timestamps to. i.e `"time": "1544785866.176123088"` The timestamps need to be unique on each iteration and need to occur on the line above "bladesetName". Unfortunately, what I have so far is not working. After printing the time to the file in the needed places I was going to add 1ns to each entry. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
timestamp() {
    date +%s.%N
}

awk "/bladesetName/{ print '"time" "$(timestamp)"' }1" volumes3.json
```

This throws an error

```
awk: /bladesetName/{ print 'time 1544786158.644385726' }1
awk:                       ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

.

```
{
"pasxml": {
    "@version": "6.0.0",
    "system": {
        "name": "example1",
        "IPV4": "0.0.0.0",
        "alertLevel": "critical",
        "state": "online"
    },
    "volumes": {
        "volume": [
            {
                "@id": "1",
                "name": "/",
                "bladesetName": {
                    "@id": "1",
                    "#text": "Set-1"
                },
                "state": "Online",
                "raid": "Object RAID6+",
                "director": "Shelf-001,1",
                "volservice": "0x0400000000000004(FM)",
                "objectId": "I-xD0200000000000004-xG7ee84b0c-xU00004a75726a656e",
                "recoveryPriority": "1",
                "efsaMode": "retry",
                "spaceUsedGB": "0",
                "spaceAvailableGB": "693903.38",
                "hardQuotaGB": "0.52",
                "softQuotaGB": "0.52",
                "userQuotaPolicy": {
                    "@inherit": "0",
                    "#text": "disabled"
                },
                "stats": null
            },
            {
                "@id": "8",
                "name": "/datacentre/archvol/pan101",
                "bladesetName": {
                    "@id": "1",
                    "#text": "Set-1"
                },
                "alertLevel": "critical",
                "state": "Online",
                "raid": "Object RAID6+",
                "director": "Shelf-008,1",
                "volservice": "0x04000000000000ec(FM)",
                "objectId": "I-xD02000000000000ec-xG5c7aef6f-xU00004a75726a656e",
                "recoveryPriority": "50",
                "efsaMode": "retry",
                "spaceUsedGB": "117000.09",
                "spaceAvailableGB": "693903.38",
                "hardQuotaGB": "117000.00",
                "softQuotaGB": "90000.00",
                "userQuotaPolicy": {
                    "@inherit": "1",
                    "#text": "disabled"
                },
                "stats": null
            },
```

Comment: using `awk` for parsing xmls and jsons is NOT recommended, so adding `jq` tag here now.

Comment: ok looking at jq, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one approach, which uses [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
def addnow: 
  . as $in
  | to_entries
  | (map(.key)|index("bladesetName")) as $i
  | if $i 
    then .[0:$i]+[{key:"time",value:now}]+.[$i:] | from_entries
    else $in 
    end ;

walk(if type=="object" then addnow else . end)
```

If you really want the time as a string, simply add `tostring`, as in `(now|tostring)`

If your jq does not have `walk`, then now would be a good time to upgrade; otherwise simply copy and paste its def, which can easily be found on the web, e.g. by googling: jq “def walk”